# Do I need to pass access tokens when using the Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm just getting started with the Graph API and the Javascript SDK.  I have a page that will authenticate users using the fb:login-button, and I have successfully posted on status updates using /me/feed.  However, when I try to retrieve a list of Events, or Posts the response is an empty array.  I've cut and pasted some of the examples from FB docs, and they result in undefined objects.

Am I missing something on authentication?  My users are authorizing user_events and friend_events.  I figured if I could post, I should be able to read.  Hoping it is something obvious.

Here is code sample that always results in the error case:

```
function getFriends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        if(response.data) {
            $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
```

and my login-button and init code:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="status_update,publish_stream,user_events,friends_events"></fb:login-button>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: 'myappid',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no you don't have to pass access_token .... maybe it is just a copy paste typo, but you miss a closing bracket in your code

Comment: Thanks, Luca.  I have the bracket closed in my source file.  I was pretty sure that I didn't need to pass it, but I can't seem to figure out what the deal is.